# Certified Professional Developer Exam reading material

Tags: magento2, certification

Recently Magento announced  **Certified Professional Developer** exam for Magento2.

After reading in this page https://u.Magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer

I have some questions about the exam.

- What is the passing score for this exam?
- Which study materials useful for preparation of this exam?
- Except from the *Free study Guide*, are there any other study materials available for this exam?
- Are there any passing criterias for the Commerce (Enterprise) edition just like we have in the Magento 1 Developer Plus Exam?
- What is the retake policy for this exam?
- How many free retakes are available?

Comment: https://www.integer-net.com/the-magento-2-online-certification-how-it-works/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=post&utm_term=blog&utm_content=online_certification&utm_campaign=magento_certification

Comment: I think there are some clear questions in your list which could be answered objectively. However you are also asking for _study materials_ which will result in loads of people posting links to all the blogs of devs and agencies out there. Maybe you could reword this? Or be more specific about what kind of/quality of materials you are looking for?

Comment: @7ochem , My intension for this question is we can collect all helpful and good resource for reading, that's it

Comment: may be some one help here https://www.goconqr.com/en-US/groups/81319

Comment: Is 2.3.0 questions included in Certified Professional Developer exam?

Comment: Right now no ...

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala you have passed the exam or not?

Comment: @HardikMakwana Passed associated one in near future planning this exam

Comment: Can you please give me some tips. I am going to give an examination in Meet Magento 2020.

Comment: @HardikMakwana Reading devDocs discussing each topics with team members and do some exp in API and checkout

Comment: I have passed this certificate I will write down my success story in the answer as well

Comment: is there any negative marks ? please let me know

Comment: @NagarajuK there is no negative marks

Answer (score 13):

Here you go:

Passing score: 64%

Free study guide is a good starting point.

Areas to focus on:

- Magento Architecture & Customization Techniques
- Request Flow Processing
- Customizing Magento UI
- Working with databases in Magento
- Using the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) Model
- Developing with Adminhtml
- Customizing Catalog
- Customizing Checkout Process
- Sales Operations
- Customer Management

You can also get a nice brief of the exam and details around it here: https://www.integer-net.com/the-magento-2-online-certification-how-it-works

Sample Test Questions: https://swiftotter.com/technical/magento-2-certified-developer-practice-test

More Info from Max Pronko: https://www.pronkoconsulting.com/ecommerce-blog/magento-2-professional-developer-certification-my-journey

Comment: +1 for your first answer, but except this topics which is already in study guide do you have any other study material

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I think exam is more practical than theoretical . Just practice more & more on these topic. For understand concepts more deeply I have shared e-books for( theme,extension development cookbook ) in whatsapp group.. ping me there so i can share more resources..

Comment: @lalitmohan can you also share the book here too. And also pm me if you can let me join your group.

Comment: @taran Is this have negative marks for unaswered question ?

Comment: @Venkat It does not.

Answer (score 6):

The Retake Policy for Magento 2 certified professional is as follows:

- You can retake this exam four times.
- You can register for the 2nd time 14 days after you failed your first one.
- You can register for the 3rd time 30 days after you failed your second one.
- The same holds for 4th & 5th time; 30 days after the previous failed one.

This means you can retake it four times after the first attempt....

[image]

Comment: That's why I added this clause , is these retake free ?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Everytime you register for an exam you have to pay for it. Means for every retake you have to pay. I guess once a year Magento offers that you can retake (only once) for FREE. However, not sure when they are going to offer it or not.

Comment: @Taran that 1+1 offer not come for last two years , but yes you get discount codes if you fail in first attempt

Comment: @Taran you can understand my point as an indian 260$ is big amount for us

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I am also an Indian :-). If you see/find ROI in certification than it will not be a big amount. I am not sure if you are working somewhere else ask your company to sponsor.

Comment: Here you go... check this URL to see the sample questions. https://swiftotter.com/technical/magento-2-certified-developer-practice-test

Answer (score 5):

To answer your questions:

**What is the passing score for this exam?**

- Passing score is 64%
- So you need to get 39 correct answers out of 60, which is almost 2 out of 3 questions.

**Which study materials useful for preparation of this exam?**

- Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Study Guide
- SwiftOtter study guide which has explanation to each official study guide questions.
- Magento DevDocs (https://devdocs.magento.com/)

**Except from the Free study Guide, are there any other study materials 
available for this exam?**

- SwiftOtter study guide which has answers/detailed information to each official study guide questions.

**Are there any passing criterias for the Commerce (Enterprise) edition just like we have in the Magento 1 Developer Plus Exam?**

- M2 Developer Plus certification is not yet launched. It should be launched end of this year.
- M2 Professional Developer does not have any Enterprise/Commerce questions.

**What is the retake policy for this exam?**

- In the event you fail the exam on your first attempt, you will be required to wait for a period of at least seven (7) calendar days before you may re-take the exam. For subsequent failed attempts, you will be required to wait either 15, 30 or 90 calendar days from the date of your last attempt before re-taking the exam, depending on the exam. (Reference: https://magento-u-support.magento.com/hc/en-us/sections/360001850452-Frequently-Asked-Questions)

**How many free retakes are available?**

- No free retakes.  In the event that you do not pass the exam, you will receive an email with information on re-testing.

My experience of the M2 Professional Developer exam: http://ka.lpe.sh/2018/08/13/magento-2-certified-professional-developer-exam-experience/

Comment: kalpesh is there any nagative marks for the exam? plz calrify

Answer (score 5):

**What is the passing score for this exam?**

64%

**Which study materials useful for preparation of this exam?**

- https://u.magento.com/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development
- [Exam Question Set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N5DY8ZJ)
- [Swift otter guide](https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-study-guide)

**Except for the Free study Guide, are there any other study materials available for this exam?**

Mentioned above.

**Are there any passing criteria for the Commerce (Enterprise) edition just like we have in the Magento 1 Developer Plus Exam?**

No

**What is the retake policy for this exam?**
You can retake 5 times with the day's intervals 7, 15, 30 and so on

**How many free retakes are available?**
No free retakes. But 20% discount for all retakes.

Answer (score 2):

```
Magento Architecture & Customization Techniques ... 11/60
Request Flow Processing ... 7/60
Customizing Magento UI ... 6/60
Working with databases in Magento ... 4/60
Using the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) Model ... 5/60
Developing with Adminhtml ... 6/60
Customizing Catalog ... 7/60
Customizing Checkout Process ... 8/60
Sales Operations ... 3/60
Customer Management ... 3/60

To pass 39/60 in Total
```

Comment: very useful information u have provided. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following study guide will help you prepare for the exam.

https://devdocs.magento.com

Swift-otter study guide

[Question set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N5DY8ZJ)