# Magento 2: understand processing order of layout handles and other directives?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, frontend, certification

I am preparing for certification on Magento 2 and I am having difficulty understanding this questions. Can anyone help me with these questions?

**Understand processing order of layout handles and other directives**

In what order are layout handles processed? In what order is layout XML merged within the same handle? How can the processing order be influenced? What are common problems arising from the merge order of layout declarations?

Comment: You can refer this link if you find help for same.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216015/certified-professional-developer-exam-reading-material