# Magento 2 Certified Professional Developers Plus Exam Reading Material

Tags: magento2, frontend, backend, certification

Recently Magento announced  **Certified Professional Developers Plus** exam for Magento2.

> https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer-plus

I have some questions about this **Certified Professional Developers Plus** exam.

- What is the passing score for developer plus exam?
- Which study materials useful for preparation of this exam except **Free study Guide**?
- What is the retake policy for this exam?
- How many free retakes are available?

Comment: you can get some idea from this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216015/certified-professional-developer-exam-reading-material

Comment: These topics are mentioned on u magento. Can you please tell the study materials instead of these and developer plus.

Comment: I think switfotter's material guide is good as per others https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-study-guide

Comment: @ChiragPatel What's duplicate, i have asked about "Certified Professional Developers Plus" not "Certified Professional Developers"

Comment: Test includes Magento EE edition modules, in EE module have more staging modules in core. So we have to foucs on Magento EE code features.

Comment: Please note the difference between the "Professional Developer Plus" and the "Professional Developer" exam. It's no duplicate.

Comment: Check https://ranasohel.me/2019/01/26/pass-magento-2-certified-professional-developer-plus-exam/

Answer (score 1):

> What is the passing score for developer plus exam?

62%, according to the link you have given.

> Which study materials useful for preparation of this exam except Free study Guide?

There are none yet. Only very few people have passed the exam. For some additional information, see [my blog post](https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer-plus/).

> What is the retake policy for this exam?

From the Email I received after failing the exam:

> You will be required to wait for a period of at least seven (7) calendar days from the date of your last attempt before you are allowed to retake the exam. For subsequent failed attempts you will be required to wait 14 days for the third attempt, 21 days for the fourth attempt and 30 days for the fifth attempt from the date of your last attempt.

I hope that answers that.

> How many free retakes are available?

None. You will receive a 20% discount though.